# Is there a way to take this data, pivot it and then combine it into a single string..?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table that contains data as follows:

```
+=========+============+=========+==============+
|   num   |  module-id | page-no |    txt       |
+=========+============+=========+==============+
| 3177564 |      1     |    1    |text string 1 |
+---------+------------+---------+--------------+
| 3177564 |      1     |    2    |text string 2 |
+---------+------------+---------+--------------+
| 3177564 |      1     |    3    |text string 3 |
+---------+------------+---------+--------------+
| 3177564 |      2     |    1    |text string 1 |
+---------+------------+---------+--------------+
| 3177564 |      2     |    2    |text string 2 |
+---------+------------+---------+--------------+
| 3177564 |      3     |    1    |text string 1 |
+---------+------------+---------+--------------+
| 3177564 |      3     |    2    |text string 2 |
+---------+------------+---------+--------------+
| 3177564 |      3     |    3    |text string 3 |
+---------+------------+---------+--------------+
```

I can then use the PIVOT function to produce the following:

```
+=========+============+==============+==============+==============+
|   num   |  module-id | page-no-1    | page-no-2    | page-no-3    | 
+=========+============+==============+==============+==============+
| 3177564 |      1     |text string 1 |text string 2 |text string 3 |
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 3177564 |      2     |text string 1 |text string 2 |NULL          |
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 3177564 |      3     |text string 1 |text string2  |text string 3 |
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

The code used to produce the pivot is:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
j.num
,jpad.[module-id]
,jpad.[page-no]
,jpad.txt
FROM
job j
LEFT OUTER JOIN jobpad jpad ON jpad.num = j.num

WHERE
(j.num IN
('3177564'))
AND (jpad.[page-no] IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)) a
PIVOT
(
MAX(a.txt) FOR a.[page-no] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])
) p
ORDER BY num
```

This is great however, what I would like to do is concatenate the data as per the following example if at all possible:

Please note that p-1, p-2 etc. refers to the page numbers.

```
+=========+=========================================================+=============+=============+
|   num   |                        module-id-1                      | module-id-2 | module-id-3 |
+=========+=========================================================+=============+=============+
| 3177564 |p-1 text string 1 & p-2 text string 2 & p-3 text string 3|per module 1 |per module 1 |
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I've been pondering this for a while now but can't quite get it right in my head.

I am currently on SQL Server 2014.

Comment: How far away are you from moving to a more modern version (2017 or newer) where `STRING_AGG` makes this much easier? Are there really only ever a max of 3 pages per num/module combination?

Comment: Hi @AaronBertrand.

Unfortunately the server upgrade could be some way off and trying the STRING_AGG function was how I found out we were on a 'legacy' server.

The number of pages for a single module could be up to 50 maybe more however, this is less of a concern (I think) because this very rarely happens.

Comment: Well, > 0 means the code must account for it. :-) Can you share the `PIVOT` query that gets your intermediate results?

Comment: Post amended to include the original PIVOT query.

Comment: Ok and if there are 10 page numbers, the columns representing page 2-10 all say “per module 1”? What is the value of including those extra columns in the output?

Comment: The values under 'module-id-2' would be pages 1 to 10 (concatenated).  The same would be for 'module-id-3'.  Does that help?

Comment: Ok I got it, I interpreted the `per module 1` you listed in the question literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first column you're after:

```
; -- see sqlblog.org/cte
WITH src AS
(
  SELECT num, [module-id], txt = STUFF(
    (SELECT CONCAT(' & ', 'p-', [page-no], ' ', txt)
      FROM dbo.StuffAndThings WHERE num = s.num
      AND [module-id] = s.[module-id]
      FOR XML PATH(''), 
      TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'varchar(max)'), 1, 3, '')
  FROM dbo.StuffAndThings AS s
  WHERE [page-no] = 1
)
SELECT num, 
  [module-id-1] = [1], 
  [module-id-2] = [2], 
  [module-id-3] = [3] 
FROM src PIVOT
(MAX(txt) FOR [module-id] IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS p;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bd0a327fa93c42a460b7dfd2d9cae8aa)

Comment: Simply superb Aaron.  That appears to have resolved the problem so many thanks for your support.  I have updated the code to allow us to extract job notes based on the reported date of the job rather than a specific job number.  This is going to save a significant amount of time post extraction so once again, many thanks.